# Modal (LeanModal) Close by Esc Key

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I am using Lean Modal for a Modal on my web app.

Lean Modal Website: http://leanmodal.finelysliced.com.au/

Its all working fine. I just want to add the event "Esc Button Click" which closes the modal. How can I do it? Please advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the demos on their homepage, you can close the modal by clicking outside it. You just  need to trigger the same click event when ESC key is pressed. This ensures that the closing is actually done by the plugin itself and not by you.

```
$(document).keyup(function(ev){
    if(ev.keyCode == 27)
        $("#lean_overlay").trigger("click");
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Do something like

```
$(window).bind('keyup',function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 27)
        $('#signup,#lean_overlay').fadeOut();
})
```

For the example on demo page

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href id="modal" tabindex="-1" >Click to open </a>
```

add tabindex="-1" if you are using jquery .